# Video stuck during video call in ios

Tags: ios, swift, pjsip, videocall

[image]I am implementing video calls using pjsip and callkit. The remote video view is coming fine and the call is happening well. But when I am trying to implement a local video view the video is stuck on the other side.

But on my side local and remote video view both working well. I tried but nothing i am getting.

Local view:-

```
struct LocalVideoView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView();
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black;
        return view;
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
            // Perform AVCaptureSession setup on a background thread
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                self.setupAVCaptureSession(uiView)
            }
        }

    func setupAVCaptureSession(_ uiView: UIView) {
            let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
            let cameraOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

            captureSession.sessionPreset = .high

            guard let frontCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) else {
                print("Front camera not available")
                return
            }



            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                }

                if captureSession.canAddOutput(cameraOutput) {
                    captureSession.addOutput(cameraOutput)
                }

                let videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

                captureSession.sessionPreset = .medium // You can adjust the preset as needed
//                videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait // Adjust orientation if needed
                if let frameRateRanges = frontCamera.activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges.first {
                    // Choose a frame rate within the supported range (e.g., 30 FPS)
                    let desiredFrameRate = min(30, frameRateRanges.maxFrameRate)

                    do {
                        try frontCamera.lockForConfiguration()
                        frontCamera.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: CMTimeScale(desiredFrameRate))
                        frontCamera.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: CMTimeScale(desiredFrameRate))
                        frontCamera.unlockForConfiguration()
                    } catch {
                        print("Error setting frame rate: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No supported frame rate ranges found for the camera.")
                }
                // Perform UI updates related to AVCaptureSession on the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    videoPreviewLayer.frame = uiView.layer.bounds
                    uiView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)
                }

                captureSession.startRunning()
            } catch {
                print("Error setting up capture session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }


    }
}
```

media state where i am passing remote video view using **PJSIP**

```
private func on_call_media_state(call_id: pjsua_call_id) {
    var ci = pjsua_call_info();
    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
    for mi in 0...ci.media_cnt {
        let media: [pjsua_call_media_info] = tupleToArray(tuple: ci.media);
        if (media[Int(mi)].status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE ||
            media[Int(mi)].status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD)
        {
            switch (media[Int(mi)].type) {
                case PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
                    var call_conf_slot: pjsua_conf_port_id;
                    call_conf_slot = media[Int(mi)].stream.aud.conf_slot;
                    pjsua_conf_connect(call_conf_slot, 0);
                    pjsua_conf_connect(0, call_conf_slot);
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: AudioCallView())
                        VidInfo.shared.vid_win = hostingController.view
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case PJMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
                    let wid = media[Int(mi)].stream.vid.win_in;
                    var wi = pjsua_vid_win_info();
                    if (pjsua_vid_win_get_info(wid, &wi) == PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue) {
                        let vid_win:UIView =
                        Unmanaged<UIView>.fromOpaque(wi.hwnd.info.ios.window).takeUnretainedValue();
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            vid_win.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2.0))
                            VidInfo.shared.vid_win = vid_win
                            print("Server view is \(String(describing: VidInfo.shared.vid_win))")
                        }
                    }
                
                
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```